# angular 2 rc1 with IE11 Object doesn't support property or method 'keys'

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11

My Angular2 RC1 code works fine with Chrome/FireFox. But when it comes to IE11, the browser emits a bunch of `Object doesn't support property or method 'keys'` error.

I have the following in index.html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.35.0/es6-sham.min.js"></script>           
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.25/system-polyfills.js"></script>      
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/angular2@2.0.0-beta.17/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
```

What else should be added to make Angular2 RC1 work with IE11?

Here is error detail

```
Error: TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'keys'
at Anonymous function (eval code:39:5)
at Anonymous function (eval code:38:1)
at Anonymous function (eval code:1:31)
at eval code (eval code:1:2)
Evaluating https://npmcdn.com/@angular/core@2.0.0-rc.1/src/facade/collection.js
Evaluating https://npmcdn.com/@angular/core@2.0.0-rc.1/src/facade/exception_handler.js
Evaluating https://npmcdn.com/@angular/core@2.0.0-rc.1/src/facade/exceptions.js
Evaluating https://npmcdn.com/@angular/core@2.0.0-rc.1/src/di/injector.js
Evaluating https://npmcdn.com/@angular/core@2.0.0-rc.1/src/di.js
Evaluating https://npmcdn.com/@angular/core@2.0.0-rc.1/index.js
Evaluating https://npmcdn.com/@angular/common@2.0.0-rc.1/src/pipes/async_pipe.js
Evaluating https://npmcdn.com/@angular/common@2.0.0-rc.1/src/pipes.js
Evaluating https://npmcdn.com/@angular/common@2.0.0-rc.1/index.js
Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/main.ts
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      description: "TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'keys'
      message: "TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'keys'
      name: "Error",
      originalErr: { },
      stack: null
   }
```

Comment: try to put `shims-for-IE` before other scripts, and try other orders maybe , it might solve the issue, just maybe.

Comment: Tried different combinations. No difference.